# Can the same training data be used for MLM and fine-tuning of a transformer model?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, transformers, data-augmentation

Can I use the same training and validation data to perform MLM and train the weights of a classification head?

Here is the background of my specific problem:
The problem is a binary classification problem using text data. I am using 'bert-base-uncased' from Huggingface. The entire data set was created using various data augmentation methods. The test set will be the original data set used to augment the data. My question is whether I can use the same data to do MLM and later train the AutoClassForSequenceClassification head.